# Can node-gyp extension call extension linked OpenSSL instead of node OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, node-gyp

Running on linux-wmxt 4.16.8-1-default (Tumbleweed).

I have a library that calls the openssl 1.0 API. I can either dynamically link or statically link. Either produces the same result.

If I run this from a C test harness, it works fine.

The same calls using node via the node-gyp extension produces memory faults which I believe are due to the calls being routed to the node version of the API calls which, I believe, uses openssl 1.1 (not ABI compatible with 1.0).

```
:
#17 0x12838e1 in ASN1_item_d2i_bio (/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.1.0/bin/node+0x12838e1)
#18 0x7f808108687e in _extractp7certs /home/me/Projects/git/test.sdk.c/c/test/src/testcrypto.c:678
:
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow
```

Exactly the same code base (statically linked) on MacOS High Sierra works fine with node 9.9.

Before diving into this any further: a simple question. Is there a way to make node-gyp ensure that my code calls my version of OpenSSL rather than Nodes? Or will I have to update my code to openssl 1.1?

Comment: I've opened an issue on node-gyp about that, https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did try various changes to binding.gyp, such as

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "myid",
      "include_dirs": [ "../dep/include" ],
      "sources": [ "./src/myid.c" ],
      "libraries": [
            "/home/me/local/lib64/libcrypto.so",
            "/home/me/local/lib64/libssl.so",
            "/home/me/local/lib64/libcurl.so",
            "/home/me/local/lib64/libxmlsec1.so",
            "../dep/slib/libmylib.so"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

These 1.0 libraries were build with:

> openssl: ./config --prefix=$HOME/local
>   --openssldir=$HOME/local/openssl
>
> libcurl: ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --with-ssl=$HOME/local
>   --disable-ldap
>
> libxmlsec1: ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --without-libxslt
>   --with-openssl=$HOME/local

Same result. So I bit the bullet and upgraded my code to be compatible with OpenSSL 1.1+.

Now the node binding works.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the binding.gyp and make it to include the lib's and include files from your version of openssl (by providing the path) in your node addon.